# Internationalization: How universal are parentheses to indicate an "aside"?

Tags: internationalization

I'm internationalizing strings in an application.  It has a few places in the settings where added text is place in parentheses to indicate an informative "aside"

For example, the user can select an icon to appear on reports.  There is a button for browsing along with the following additional text

> (appears on reports)

Or sometimes I want to show that a value could not be known but I want to indicate that it's actually not known as opposed to it's value being the literal text "unknown".  So I will put it in parentheses

> (unknown)

In both cases I've used parentheses to indicate this.  How do my parentheses translate to other languages and cultures?  Is there some other, better internationalization mechanism for indicating these situations?

Comment: Also in English, it is not the only way. On paper media: footnotes, sidenotes are frequent. On new media: mouse-over is also used. -- In any case, there is the problem on which parenthesis is open and which close the aside (it depends on left-to-right, and right-to-left). -- Personally: parenthesis are part of translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're writing an English-only application then it doesn't matter, just be consistent and most people would get it.

For localized applications the best practice is to decouple user facing strings from code to give your translators and editors flexibility to decide what to use.

So if your have string "Icon (appears on reports)" then consider a few options:

```
<span>{{ _t('Icon') }} {{ _t('(appears on reports)') }}</span> // troubles expected

<span>{{ _t('Icon (appears on reports)') }}</span>             // okay
<span>{{ _t('icon_appears_on_reports') }}</span>               // the best practice
```

In this way English editor and translators would be able to decide, for example:

```
EN: "Icon (appears on reports)" or "Icon, appears on reports" etc
RU: "Знак для отображения в отчетах"
```

Comment: Thank you.   I actually decided to do as you recommend but it's good to have my suspicions confirmed.